# List and Contains method

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i have this problem: starting from an empty list (0 elements) i want check if an element is present or not present in this list. In case this record not is present in list then i add this record to list, otherwise update element in list.
I have tried writing this code:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections, System.Generics.Defaults;

type
  TDBStats = record
    Comb: Integer;
    Freq: Integer;
  end;
  TDBStatsList = TList<TDBStats>;

procedure Add(ODBStats: TDBStatsList; const Item: TDBStats);
var
  rItem: TDBStats;
begin
  rItem := Item;
  rItem.Freq := 1;
  oDBStats.Add(rItem);
end;

procedure Update(ODBStats: TDBStatsList; const Item: TDBStats; const Index: Integer);
var
  rItem: TDBStats;
begin
  rItem := Item;
  Inc(rItem.Freq);
  oDBStats[Index] := rItem;
end;


var
  oDBStats: TDBStatsList;
  rDBStats: TDBStats;
  myArr: array [0..4] of integer;
  iIndex1: Integer;
begin
  try
    myArr[0] := 10;
    myArr[1] := 20;
    myArr[2] := 30;
    myArr[3] := 40;
    myArr[4] := 10;

    oDBStats := TList<TDBStats>.Create;
    try
      for iIndex1 := 0 to 4 do
      begin
        rDBStats.Comb := myArr[iIndex1];
        if oDBStats.Contains(rDBStats) then
          Update(oDBStats, rDBStats, oDBStats.IndexOf(rDBStats))
        else
          Add(oDBStats, rDBStats);
      end;
      // Check List
      for iIndex1 := 0 to Pred(oDBStats.Count) do
        Writeln(oDBStats[iIndex1].Comb:3, oDBStats[iIndex1].Freq:10);
    finally
      oDBStats.Free;
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

and should return this result:

```
10     2
20     1
30     1
40     1
50     1
```

but return this result:

```
10     1
20     1
30     1
40     1
50     1
10     1
```

I have understood about problem: when i use oDBStats.Contains(rDBStats) it control if rDBStats element is contained in list; the first time not found it and add in list; but when it is added in list i update freq field to 1; so second time when i check again being rdbstats with freq = 0 not found it.
As i can solve this problem? I need to have a counter, where i get from input a "comb" and i want check if this "comb" is present in list, indipendetely from value of the other field of the record. In case i find "comb" in list, then i update, increasing freq field.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Your code is difficult to read because of randomly chosen type names; use `TDBStatList` instead of `TDBStats`, `TDBStat` instead of `PDBStats`.

Comment: Done, so i hope that it help better.

Comment: `Freq` field value is also tested in `Contains` method; simply adding `rDBStats.Freq := 1;` line after `rDBStats.Comb := myArr[iIndex1];` gives correct result, but that is not general solution; you need a different comparer for your list.

Comment: I still can't see where the output `50 1` comes from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `Contains` on a generic list, it looks if the given value is already inside the list. The value in your case is a record which consists of two fields. As you didn't specify a custom comparer, Delphi will use a default comparer which in case of a record does a binary compare. So only when two records are binary equal they will be treated as equal.

To make your example work you have to specify a custom comparer that compares only the comb field of the records. This is an example:

```
oDBStats := TList<TDBStats>.Create(TDelegatedComparer<TDBStats>.Create(
 function(const Left, Right: TDBStats): Integer
 begin
   result := CompareValue(Left.comb, Right.comb);
 end));
```

In addition you have an error in your update routine. Instead of incrementing the existing value, you are incrementing the undefined value of the item parameter. The change in the first line should make it work:

```
  rItem := oDBStats[Index];
  Inc(rItem.Freq);
  oDBStats[Index] := rItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong data structure since what you really need is a [dictionary](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary).

The fundamental problem with using a list is that you want to search on a *subset* of the stored record. But lists are not set up for that. Solve the problem by re-writing using `TDictionary<Integer, Integer>`.

I can recommend that you have a thorough read of the [dictionary code example at the Embarcadero docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/Generics.Collections.TDictionary_%28Delphi%29).

The key to the dictionary is what you call `comb` and the value is `freq`. To add an item you do this:

```
if Dict.TryGetValue(Comb, Freq) then
  Dict[Comb] := Freq+1
else
  Dict.Add(Comb, 1);
```

I'm assuming your dictionary is declared like this:

```
var
  Dict: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
```

and created like this:

```
Dict := TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
```

You can enumerate the dictionary with a simple `for in` loop.

```
var
  Item: TPair<Integer, Integer>;
...
  for Item in Dict do
    Writeln(Item.Key:3, Item.Value:10);
```

Although be warned that the dictionary will enumerate in an odd order. You may wish to sort before printing.

If you wish to store more information associated with each entry in the dictionary then put the additional fields in a record.

```
type
  TDictValue = record
    Freq: Integer;
    Field1: string;
    Field2: TDateTime;
    //etc.
  end;
```

Then your dictionary becomes `TDictionary<Integer, TDictValue>`.

Comment: Thanks for suggest, i looked here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/Generics_Collections_TDictionary_(Delphi) and about example i have understood; but i have a small problem to understand as i can to do in my case. In particular, in type section as i declare it? For example i have: TDBStatsList = TList<TDBStats> and should write: TDBStatsList = TDictionary<PDBStats, Comb>; but it turn me an error in Comb. If i understood well this "comb" represent primary key. Can try to give an example where i can understand better; sincerly it first time that i use tdictionary. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, i have just read your example. I try it. Thanks again very much

Comment: i have simplified that record TDBStats using just two field: comb (as primary key) and freq as generic field; in real application this record is formed of much fields where this fields are updated all time that is get an element comb. Looking your example i should add all this fields to: Dict.TryGetValue(Comb, Freq) having something as: Dict.TryGetValue(Comb, Freq, Field1, field2, fieldn)? Taking as example code that i posted i can only update the section where i check if element exists or not using Tdictionary?

Comment: You need to put the various fields that make up the key into a single record.

Comment: Actually, on second reading maybe all the extra fields belong in the value rather than the key. Only you can know. You can work out whether a field should be key or value based on whether or not you need search on the key. Also, Uwe's answer would be a viable alternative but your data structure does sound more like a dictionary to me. That said, dictionaries are not flexible and don't allow searching with different keys. You have to decide up front what your search key is. Uwe's answer can be adapted to allow different search keys at runtime.

Comment: In general i have a database that contains an element that i called: COMB. Here, i read this element COMB and in a new data-structure (for example a list, or a dictionary) i need to check if this element COMB is present in it. If not is present then i add this element and initialize it with default value; otherwise if it is present simply i update all field of this element. This becouse element COMB in my database can to be present much time; is as if i want implement much counter with different rules where one of this is freq. That count how much time element COMB is present in my database.

Comment: (continue) The primary key in this case is only one: COMB. And other field are associated to this key.

Comment: Well I would certainly use a dictionary but you see to prefer the other option. You should know that searching lists is slower than dictionaries. The latter use a hash. You make it worse in your code by calling `Contains` and then `IndexOf`. That will result in two linear searches when one suffices.