# Record equality in generic collections

Tags: delphi, generics, operator-overloading, delphi-xe2, record

Assume you have a record with an overloaded equality operator

```
TSomeRecord = record
  Value : String;
  class operator Equal(Left, Right : TSomeRecord) : Boolean;
end;
```

(implementation compares string values). If adding two records to the list that are equal based on the overloaded operator I would expect the `Contains` method to return true in both cases. But in fact, the generic list seems to just compare the memory content of records instead of applying the overloaded equality operator.

```
var
  List : TList <TSomeRecord>;
  Record1,
  Record2 : TSomeRecord;

begin
Record1.Value := 'ABC';
Record2.Value := 'ABC';
List.Add(Record1);

Assert(List.Contains(Record1));
Assert(List.Contains(Record2));    //  <--- this is not true
end;
```

Is this the expected behaviour? Any explanations?

Comment: How does the Equal operator impl look like? Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862807/list-and-contains-method

Comment: In general, records do not support the `=` operator, and it's impossible to detect in code whether any particular type supports it, so the default implementation must use simple memory comparison for all types that it doesn't have *a priori* knowledge of.

Comment: Thanks @RobKennedy, then it would be nice to have an equality constraint on generic types that would ensure the existence of an equality operator.

Comment: @Smasher There are lots of constrains that would be nice. For example if we could constrain arithmetic operators then we could write generic maths algorithms

Comment: Yes, that was just a day-dreaming thought :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you did not specify a comparer in the constructor to `TList.Create` you will get `TComparer<TSomeRecord>.Default` as your comparer. And that is a comparer that performs simple binary comparison using `CompareMem`.

That's fine for a record full of value types, with no padding. But otherwise you will need to supply your own compare function when you instantiate the list.

If you want to look at the details, the default comparer for records is implemented in `Generics.Defaults`. For larger records the equality comparer is this function:

```
function Equals_Binary(Inst: PSimpleInstance; const Left, Right): Boolean;
begin
  Result := CompareMem(@Left, @Right, Inst^.Size);
end;
```

For smaller records there is an optimization and your comparer will be the 4 byte comparer. That looks like this:

```
function Equals_I4(Inst: Pointer; const Left, Right: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Left = Right;
end;
```

That's a bit weird, but it interprets the 4 bytes of your record as a 4 byte integer and performs integer equality comparison. In other words, the same as `CompareMem`, but more efficient.

The comparer that you want to use might look like this:

```
TComparer<TSomeRecord>.Construct(
  function const Left, Right: TSomeRecord): Integer
  begin
    Result := CompareStr(Left.Value, Right.Value);
  end;
)
```

Use `CompareText` if you want case insensitive, and so on. I've used an ordered comparison function because that's what `TList<T>` wants.

The fact that the default record comparison is an equality comparison tells you that attempts to sort lists of records without specifying your own comparer will have unexpected results.

Given that the default comparer uses an equality comparison tells you that it would not be totally unreasonable to use a comparer like this:

```
TComparer<TSomeRecord>.Construct(
  function const Left, Right: TSomeRecord): Integer
  begin
    Result := ord(not (Left = Right));
  end;
)
```

That will be fine for unordered operations like `IndexOf` or `Contains` but obviously no use at all for sorting, binary search and so on.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for explanation. Does that mean that it is in general not possible to write a generic type that just uses the equality operator so that the equality built into the types is used without specifying a custom comparer?

Comment: @Smasher That's right. The generics framework just will not look for your equality operator. In any case, as I explained in my updated, the list class wants more than an equality comparison. It wants to be able to order the elements. That's so that it can sort.

Comment: So there's no way to correctly define equality without thinking about ordering - which does not make sense in my scenario?

Comment: You could change the anonymous comparison function to do `Result := ord(Left=Right)` and that would have the right meaning for `IndexOf`, `Contains` etc. But would result in chaos if you attempted to sort. Since the default comparer in `Generics.Default` uses `CompareMem`, you'd be committing no worse a crime than that. So, if you don't use operations that rely on order, feel free to base it on your equality operator, via a comparer.

Comment: Isn't `Result := ord(Left=Right);` a typo? If `Left=Right` then `Result` will equal `ord(True)`, that is, `1`, which is not `0`. `Result := ord(not (Left=Right));` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 3):

To get the expected behavior you have to create the List with a comparer.

In this case you should use

```
List := TList<TSomeRecord>.Create( TComparer<TSomeRecord>.Construct(
  function ( const L, R : TSomeRecord ) : Integer
  begin
    Result := CompareStr( L.Value, R.Value );
  end ) );
```

Comment: yes, it is just weird for me that I have to specify the equality logic twice. Note that the comparer that does just `Result := L = R` works equally well. That's why I was surprised that the generic collections can't handle it without the comparer.

Comment: ah..correct. So I have to think about ordering (which I don't need) to get correct equality comparisons? Just doesn't feel right....

Comment: @Smasher: You need to think about ordering because `TList<T>` uses the `TComparer` for sorting as well as checking equality.