# IS this declaration good: TDictionary<TPair<int32, int64>, bool>

Tags: delphi

I declare this object

```
MyDict := TDictionary<TPair<int32, int64>, bool>.create([]);
MyDict.add(TPair<Int32, Int64>.create(2, 0), true);
```

why

```
MyDict.TryGetValue(TPair<int32, int64>.create(2, 0), result)
```

can not found the previous key I just added?

Comment: Maybe this question can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920502/record-equality-in-generic-collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the default equality comparer for `TPair<TKey,TValue>` tests naive binary equality for the record. In your case the record specialises as:

```
TPair<int32,int64> = record
  Key: int32;
  Value: int64;
end;
```

Because the record is aligned, there is padding. There are four bytes of padding between `Key` and `Value`. The values of this padding is then used by the default comparer.

If you could define your own type, instead of using `TPair<TKey,TValue>` then you could declare it packed. That will be fine for simple value types as you use here for `TKey` and `TValue`, but more complex non-value types then even that would fail.

The other approach is to define your own equality comparer, and pass it to the dictionary constructor. You can do this by calling `TEqualityComparer<TPair<TKey,TValue>>.Contruct()` passing an equality comparison function and a hasher function. See this question for an example: [What is the canonical way to write a hasher function for TEqualityComparer.Construct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294686/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-write-a-hasher-function-for-tequalitycomparer-const)